# Is there a reason that sine substitution is preferred to cosine substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration, soft-question

When integrating by trigonometric substitution that has $\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$ in the integrand, the general recommended approach is to make the substitution $x = a \sin\theta$, and this substitution is the one shown in countless place, with the accompanying proof.

However, I have never seen the substitution $x = a\cos\theta$, which seems odd, since it seems the proof would work equally well for cosine as it does for sine. Is there any particular reason this substitution seems to never be used, besides custom?

Comment: Not really.  Perhaps there is the fact that on intervals within $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, the cosine function is decreasing, so after substituting into a definite integral, the limits of integration will be the "wrong" way around.  But this is a very weak reason, especially as there will be a negative sign because $\frac{dx}{d\theta}=-a\sin\theta$ and the limits immediately come the "right" way around again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two substitutions are virtually identical.  A slight complication arises if you set $x=a\cos(\theta)$, for then $dx=-a\sin(\theta)d\theta$.  Note that you pick up a minus sign that you don't pick up with $x=a\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: The complication is illusory as $\cos$ (without the minus sign) can be negative and $\sin$ can be negative too, rendering $-\sin$ positive.